# Difficulty with listserv how is it suppose to work

Tags: mailing-lists

Hello I subscribe to a mailing list but I don't see any posts from anyone else. All that I am able to do is post to the group. What am I doing wrong how is this supposed to work?

Comment: We might need more details such as which mailing list, which email client etc

Comment: In addition to what client are you using, how is the client configured?